# Assignment operators in if statement

Tags: c

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = -1;

if (b = a || b == ++c )
    a+=3;
```

Why are the values of a,b and c 3 , 1, 0 respectively? More specifically, why is b 1 and not 0?

Comment: Why did you expect it to be 0?

Comment: With parens to clarify the order of operations:
`if (b = ( a || (b == ++c) ) )`

Comment: @sri.vatsa: "why is b 1 and not 0"... Why not?

Comment: Moral of the story: _Always remember your parentheses_

Comment: Thanks! i figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are clear with the precedence of operators,it will be easy for you to tackle such type of questions.Go through  [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)  to know about operator precedence in C.

You should see my answer after going through the precedence list  because then it will get more easily  inside your mind.

> Now,coming to your question....

Out of all the operators used in the above code, `++c` has the highest precedence.So the value of `c` becomes `0` and then value of `c` is compared to value of `b` here  `b == ++c` which evaluates to `true` i.e `1` and now `||` of `1` and `a` is taken which is `1`.

And finally this result `1` is assigned  to `b`.So the overall execution of `if` statement evaluates to true and value of `a` is incremented by `3`.

Hence finally the value of `a=3,b=1 and c=0`.

Answer (score 6):

Because `||` has higher precedence than `=`, so it's being parsed as if you'd written.

```
if (b = (a || (b == ++c)))
```

This calculates `a || (b == ++c)`. This is true because `b == 0` and `++c == 0`, so `b == ++c` is true, and true is `1`.

Add parentheses to get what you want:

```
if ((b = a) || (b == ++c))
```

But IMHO it's generally best to avoid writing such complex expressions. Do them as separate statements:

```
b = a;
if (b || b == ++c)
```

Comment: I wonder whether the intention was to write `if ( b == a || b == ++c )` in the first place.

Comment: "Add parentheses to get what you want:" How did you come to the conclusion that this is what the OP wants? If we started jumping to conclusions, the first conclusion we'd probably want to jump to would be that the OP actually wanted `b == a`, not `b = a`.

Comment: Because he said he expected `b` to be `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Also, the title says "Assignment operators in if statement", which makes me believe the assignment is intentional.

Comment: @Barmar: But `b == a || b == ++c` would also leave `b` as `0`.

Comment: Not to brag, but one of the reasons I've gotten such high reputation as I have in the time I've been here is because I'm very good at figuring out what people intend. I've been doing this for decades on Usenet.

Comment: @Barmar: Um... I've been doing it on Usenet too, but with all due respect I believe neither you nor I get to say this about ourselves. "Very good at figuring out what people intend" - this is something for those other people to conclude and to say. Sorry.

Comment: *Not to brag*? That comments is all about bragging. Not that you don't deserve it :) :)